# How to attach css while Sending html emails with PHP

Tags: php, html, css, email

i've to send email on registration . Right now this is  what i'm doing ,

```
$bodymessaage= '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >';
$bodymessaage.='</table>'
```

my images are live on server and i've set their paths as absolute , i've set these headers

```
<?php $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";?>
```

and in mail function is like this .

```
mail($to, $subject, $bodymessaage, $headers);
```

now mail is being sent with with all images and stles that are inline , my question is how do i attach css file that is in head section of my  html email in style tags  ,Please help me to sort this issue ,

Answer (score 2):

Use html `style` tag. I'm not 100% sure, but I believe it should come before the html `body`.

```
$bodymessage = '
<style>
   table{
   background-color: blue;
   }
</style>
';
$bodymessaage .= '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >';
$bodymessaage .='</table>';
```

This is just an example, of course.

As mentioned by Fred, `<style>` tags are ignored by most email clients. So instead of using it, use inline CSS:

```
$bodymessaage .= '<table style="background-color: blue;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >';
$bodymessaage .='</table>';
```

Comment: style tags are ignored by most email clients, especially Google, Hotmail, Yahoo. Best to use inline CSS.

Comment: Inline CSS would be `style=" "` in the HTML element, right?

Comment: that is exactly it. The first one will fail for the most part, while the second will work.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that.

Comment: oh and you forgot a closing semi-colon here `$bodymessaage .='</table>'` ;-)